# Is it possible to give Union Queries an Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, servlets

Is it possible to give each Union query a "title" in SQL?

For example:

```
SELECT Name, Address
From Table1
Where .....

UNION

SELECT name, Address
From Table2
Where .....
```

Is it possible to label/alias the whole query from table 1 as "Results from table 1" and table 2 "results as table 2"

If there is a better way to do it, i.e. javascript, jquery, append tables together, etc, please let me know!

Tech Stack I am using:
SQL Server 2008, JSP, Servlets, javascript, jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A union returns a set of results indistinguishable from a single query, add a column?

```
select 'T1', Name, Address
union
select 'T2', Name, Address
```

Or see if you client provider supports multiple recordsets and execute the 2 selects in a single batch, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378758.aspx

Comment: perfect, adding a column makes me distinguish which query/table it came from, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
select name, Address, 'Table1' as Source
from Table1
where.....

union

select name, Address, 'Table2'
from Table2
where.....
```

Comment: +1 Note that by doing this you've lost the deduplicating power of the `UNION` since the new `Source` column makes the two sets distinct. If this is not needed, then the efficiency could be improved by using `UNION ALL` instead.